# C# not getting data from Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a problem sending ajax data from my javascript file to my c# controller. I get a "bad request error" in my c# program, and the reason i get that is because the data parameter "result" which i am sending with ajax is not getting received by c# and the c# variable stays null. I know Ajax is routing to the correct controller since it is calling the method, but the variable "result" is not getting received by c# for some reason.

Here is my ajax request.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   data: { 'result' : result },
   url: "https://localhost:44374/api/task",
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
   // Process the received data.
   }
});
```

Here is my c# controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<string> Get(string result)
    {
        string id = result;
        getTaskContent(id);
        return id;
    }
```

After changing Ajax to GET, the program works and the output is:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:44374/api/task/1108164994166723?_=1549876832637 application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost:Information: Request finished in 17.8526ms 404
```

But for some reason the C# Actionresult method is not getting executed.

See that the URL is `localhost:44374/api/task/1108164994166723?_=1549876832637`, where the result variable is `1108164994166723`, what I have no idea about is how the `?_=1549876832637` part is coming. If I alert the result variable in the window it is only 1108164994166723

**Solution**

The combination of changing to GET instead of POST and the changing URL in Ajax to `url: "localhost:44374/api/task?result=" + result`, did the job.

Correct Ajax code is:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   url: "https://localhost:44374/api/task?result=" + result
});
```

Comment: Your controller has a `HttpGet` annotation filter and you're making a `POST` request for starters... not sure if it's calling the right method at all.

Comment: Why you have a comma after result? If the data sent is in JSON format you can't add comma at the end of the json

Comment: None of those two fixed the problem, removed the comma, changed to Get

Comment: Your second problem is that data isn't set like that using a GET request. Add the data to url not the body of the request.

Comment: I tried adding the result variable to the URL, but I got stuck on how to retrieve the variable in c#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing the content-type to "application/json;charset=utf-8" and sending the parameter name in the URL like this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
   url: "https://localhost:44374/api/task?result=" + result,
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
   // Process the received data.
   }
});
```

Comment: the "url" part did the job and by changing the POST to GET.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `GET` method in the controller to `POST` method. Since in your ajax call you are specifying the type as post.

Answer (score 0):

you must changeto HttpPost in Controller and change the result type to JsonResult.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `type` to `type:GET` -- because your controller action method is a HTTPGET and `contentType` to: `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8` 
and `data` to `data: JSON.stringify({ result: result })`